# Can a range be matched in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, range, matching

Is it possible to match a range of values in Scala?

For example:

```
val t = 5
val m = t match {
    0 until 10 => true
    _ => false
}
```

`m` would be `true` if `t` was between 0 and 10, but false otherwise. This little bit doesn't work of course, but is there any way to achieve something like it?

Comment: Note that by writing "0 until 10" you mean 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 (including 0, excluding 10). If you want to include 10, use "0 to 10".

Comment: See a related stackoverflow question: [How can I pattern match on a range in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160888/how-can-i-pattern-match-on-a-range-in-scala)

Comment: The title asks for how to match a value of type `Range` against several possibilities, e.g. "Do I have `(0..5)` or `(1..6)`?"

Comment: `val m = 0 until 10 contains t` is effectively the same but shorter. it will get you the true/false answer. If a boolean answer is all you are after.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Guard using `Range`:

```
val m = t match {
  case x if 0 until 10 contains x => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: what about Double? 0.1 and 10.0

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev what's about it?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov how to implement it? Could you add an example for doubles? The step will be 0.1, not 1.

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev in REPL: `scala> 0.0 until 10.0 by 0.1 contains 4.0`, returns

`res0: Boolean = true`

Answer (score 34):

You can use guards:

```
val m = t match {
    case x if (0 <= x && x < 10) => true
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: In terms of performance this solution is better than @alexander-azarov solution. There the Range needs to be initialised followed by a range scan. Especially for large ranges this can become a problem.

Comment: `Range.contains` is of course overridden so it doesn't need to scan anything! It's still a bit of extra code, but Hotspot should inline and optimize it without problem.

Answer (score 4):

With these definitions:

```
  trait Inspector[-C, -T] {
    def contains(collection: C, value: T): Boolean
  }

  implicit def seqInspector[T, C <: SeqLike[Any, _]] = new Inspector[C, T]{
    override def contains(collection: C, value: T): Boolean = collection.contains(value)
  }

  implicit def setInspector[T, C <: Set[T]] = new Inspector[C, T] {
    override def contains(collection: C, value: T): Boolean = collection.contains(value)
  }

  implicit class MemberOps[T](t: T) {
    def in[C](coll: C)(implicit inspector: Inspector[C, T]) =
      inspector.contains(coll, t)
  }
```

You can do checks like these:

```
2 in List(1, 2, 4)      // true
2 in List("foo", 2)     // true
2 in Set("foo", 2)      // true
2 in Set(1, 3)          // false
2 in Set("foo", "foo")  // does not compile
2 in List("foo", "foo") // false (contains on a list is not the same as contains on a set)
2 in (0 to 10)          // true
```

So the code you need would be:

```
val m = x in (0 to 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to match using a range:

```
val m = t match {
  case x if ((0 to 10).contains(x)) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: This duplicates @Alexander Azarov's answer.

Comment: Wrong match for t == 10.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to actually add this to the language using implicits, i added two variations for int and Range

```
object ComparisonExt {
  implicit class IntComparisonOps(private val x : Int) extends AnyVal {
    def between(range: Range) = x >= range.head && x < range.last
    def between(from: Int, to: Int) = x >= from && x < to
  }

}

object CallSite {
  import ComparisonExt._

  val t = 5
  if (t between(0 until 10)) println("matched")
  if (!(20 between(0 until 10))) println("not matched")
  if (t between(0, 10)) println("matched")
  if (!(20 between(0, 10))) println("not matched")
}
```