# Pattern match on range in Scala with Spark udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching, user-defined-functions

I have a Spark DataFrame which contains Strings which I am matching to numeric scores, using a Likert scale. Different question Ids map to different scores. I'm trying to pattern match on a range in Scala within an Apache Spark udf, using this question as a guide:

[How can I pattern match on a range in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160888/how-can-i-pattern-match-on-a-range-in-scala)

But I'm getting a compilation error when I use a range rather than a simple OR statement, 
i.e.

`31 | 32 | 33 | 34` works fine

`31 to 35` doesn't compile. Any ideas where I'm going wrong on the syntax please?

Also, in the final case _, I'd like to map to a String rather than an Int,
`case _ => "None"` but this gives an error: 
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported`

Presumably this is an issue which is generic to Spark, as it's perfectly possible to return `Any` in native Scala?

Here's my code:

```
def calculateScore = udf((questionId: Int, answerText: String) => (questionId, answerText) match {

      case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Rarely /<br>Never") => 4 //this is fine
      case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Occasionally") => 3
      case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Often") => 2
      case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Almost always /<br>Always") => 1
      case ((x if 41 until 55 contains x), "None of the time") => 1 //this line won't compile
      case _ => 0 //would like to map to "None"
    })
```

The udf then gets used on a Spark DataFrame, as follows:

```
val df3 = df.withColumn("NumericScore", calculateScore(df("QuestionId"), df("AnswerText")))
```

Comment: The idea of a UDF is that it returns a result that could be used in a SQL statement. So, it needs to be an Int, a String or some other supported type. *Any* doesn't make any sense in the context of SQL. Here, you're doing something essentially similar, just using dataframes rather than SQL directly. Still, if you really want different behavior in your wildcard case (and I don't understand why you would), perhaps you could return -1 or something like that. Alternatively, make the other cases return Strings.

Comment: @Phasmid I'm cleaning up a datafile which I'm performing analytics on. The file is currently formatted as a long list of questions which I'm pivoting the responses to. Some of the responses need to be strings, others Ints, doubles etc. I'll set the schema for each when I've pivoted the data. So I need the output of the column to be flexible - hence the use of Any. Using -1 is a good idea though.

Comment: But I realise that use of Any isn't possible, so I'll use strings rather than ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guarding expression should be put after the pattern:

```
def calculateScore = udf((questionId: Int, answerText: String) => (questionId, answerText) match {
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Rarely /<br>Never") => 4 
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Occasionally") => 3
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Often") => 2
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Almost always /<br>Always") => 1
  case (x, "None of the time") if 41 until 55 contains x => 1
  case _ => 0 //would like to map to "None"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map the last `case` i.e. `case _` to "None" `String`, then all of the case should return `String` as well

Following `udf` function should work for you

```
def calculateScore  = udf((questionId: Int, answerText: String) => (questionId, answerText) match {
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Rarely /<br>Never") => "4" //this is fine
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Occasionally") => "3"
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Often") => "2"
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Almost always /<br>Always") => "1"
  case (x, "None of the time") if (x >= 41 && x < 55) => "1" //this line won't compile
  case _ => "None"
})
```

If you want to map the last `case` i.e. `case _` to `None`, then you would need to change the other return types as child of `Option` as `None` is child of `Option`

Following code should also work for you

```
def calculateScore  = udf((questionId: Int, answerText: String) => (questionId, answerText) match {
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Rarely /<br>Never") => Some(4) //this is fine
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Occasionally") => Some(3)
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Often") => Some(2)
  case ((31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35), "Almost always /<br>Always") => Some(1)
  case (x, "None of the time") if (x >= 41 && x < 55) => Some(1) //this line won't compile
  case _ => None
})
```

The final point is that the error message you have `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported` clearly states that `udf` function with return type `Any` is not supported. All the `return types` from the `match cases` should be consistent.

Comment: Both these answers were super helpful, thanks to you both