# Pattern match for Integer range

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

The purpose of my function is to add 5 to an integer as long as that integer is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 7.  I try:

```
val add5Partial : PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case d if (0 < d <= 7) => d + 5;
}
```

I get:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(7)
 required: Boolean
         case d if (0 < d <= 7) => d + 5;
```

Any tips?

Comment: om-nom-nom has the answer. To my knowledge, _no_ common modern programming language allows the kind of shorthand notation you used. Note, too, that you don't need the outer-most parentheses surrounding the guard expression and semicolons in Scala are very bad style! Also, only put a space to the left of a colon when you're using the context bound syntax.

Comment: @RandallSchulz python can do this. Actually I've seen that somebody on scala mailing list done this with scala as well, but with some additional trickery. Cant find it now.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346127/can-a-range-be-matched-in-scala.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Scala do not support such syntax out of the box, so you have to write:

```
val partial : Int => Int = {
  case d if (d > 0) && (d <= 7) => d + 5;
}
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
val partial : Int => Int = {
  case d if 1 to 7 contains d => d + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this in a single comparison. You need to use:

```
(d > 0) && (d <= 7)
```

As you have done it, it will evaluate one comparison to a Boolean and then fail to use this as an int in the second comparison.

Answer (score 5):

You can do any of the following:

```scala
val f = (n: Int) ⇒ if (n > 0 && n <= 7) n + 5 else n
```

// or ...

```scala
def f(n: Int) = if (n > 0 && n <= 7) n + 5 else n
```

// or ...

```scala
def f(n: Int): Int = n match {
    case n if n > 0 && n <= 7 ⇒ n + 5
    case _ ⇒ n
}
```

// or (to speak of ... the comment by @om-nom-nom)

```scala
def f(n: Int) = n match {
    case n if 0 to 7 contains n ⇒ n + 5
    case _ ⇒ n
}
```